# URL hacking for visualforce pages?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

I'm stuck on one part of my project. The requirements are:
On the tasks related list on the contact page layout,create a  **list btn (not sure if you can do that on tasks)** which creates a new task directing the user to the Task record type selector and then to a prepopulated VF page. Once they click save, then the record is saved.

**Can I do this through URL hacking? What’s the right approach?**

For our s-control we’re building the url by something like this:

```
params = '/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Task';
params += '&' + 'retURL' + '=' + retURL;
params += '&' + 'save_new_url' + '=' +  '%2F00T%2Fe';
```

Comment: s-control!!! http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/S-Control_Deprecation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible, the formula for the task list view button would be something like this (adjust for your vf page and param names).

```
{!URLFOR($Action.Task.NewTask, null, [retURL=URLFOR($Action.Contact.View,Contact.Id),
    save_new_url="/apex/yourvfpage?param1=" + Contact.Id + 
    "&param2=" + Contact.Name + "test"])}
```

Upon selecting the record type the above link would look like

```
/apex/yourvfpage?param1=test&param2=test&RecordType=01270000000LufM&ent=Task
```

Your visualforce page would be responible for reading your custom params and the RecordType param to default the values on the task.

Comment: use the formula builder for the custom button to insert the values into place of param1 and param2, you're syntax is almost correct, you just don't need the curly brackets if you're already inside a curly bracket

Comment: updated answer to include an example